# Google ML Kit, BarcodeScannerOptions Adding barcode reading type dynamically

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, google-mlkit

I added select buttons. However, I cannot transfer the data here to the options section.
my codes are as follows. How can I add the dark parts programmatically?

BarcodeScannerOptions options = new BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
.setBarcodeFormats(***settings.getBarcodeEan13(),settings.getBarcodeEan8()***).build();

public BarcodeScannerProcessor(Context context, ExchangeScannedData exchangeScannedData) {
super(context);

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nztio.png)

```
    settings = new Settings(context);

    // Comment this code if you want to allow open Barcode format.
    BarcodeScannerOptions options = new BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
            .setBarcodeFormats(settings.getBarcodeEan13(),settings.getBarcodeEan8()).build();

    barcodeScanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient(options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is you can compute the supported formats manually.

```
int supportedFormats = 0
for each format from settings
  supportedFormats |= format
options = new BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder().setBarcodeFormats(supportedFormats).build()
```

Comment: This answer is very correct. This is how I was able to resolve the Integer data type. Thank you. @zhouyi